# Computing the $f_{Y|X}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ over the unit circle

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

> Assume the random variable $(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed on the disc $B=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2\leqslant 1\}$
>   Determine the conditional distribution:

From a previous answer I have been able to compute the following density conditional distribution $f_{Y|X}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

I want to compute the cumulative conditional  distribution. However I do not know how to define the boundaries for the double integral of $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-x^2}}$.

**Question**:

How should I solve the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "I have been able to compute the following density conditional distribution"  A formula is not a function. Which is  the variable in that function, and which is its domain? Did you attempt to graph it (even in your mind) ?

Comment: @leonbloy I thought  the domain was $B$, hence the need of a double integral.

Comment: The joint density is a bivariate funciton, the conditional density is a univariate function, it depends on a single variable, hence its domain cannot be a 2D region! You need to rethink that, and try to think of it graphically , say https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bw0eVV3RxA8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simpler (but geometric) view of the problem.

- The joint pdf of $X$ and $Y$ can be thought of as defining a *surface* above the $x$-$y$ plane with the property that the *volume* trapped between the surface and the $x$-$y$ plane is $1$.  What is the surface for your problem? If you think of the volume of the *solid* defined by $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ and the $x$-$y$ plane as being $1$, what does the *solid* loo like in your problem?
- The value of the marginal pdf of $X$ at $x_0$ is found by integrating the function $f_{X,Y}(x_0,y)$ with respect to $y$ from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. Here, $x_0$ is a *constant* (say, $0.6$) and not a variable. Think of $f_{X,Y}(0.6,y)$ as the *cross-section* of the $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ solid at $x=0.6$ so that $f_X(0.6)$ is given by the *area* of the cross-section being looked at. What does this cross-section look like for *your* solid?
- The conditional pdf of $Y$ given that $X$ equals $0.6$ is defined as $\displaystyle \frac{f_{X,Y}(0.6,y)}{f_X(0.6)}$. It is a *function* of $y$ (which occurs only in the numerator -- the denominator is just a constant.  Well, you already know what $f_{X,Y}(0.6,y)$ looks like as a function of $y$ (you don't? go back to the previous paragraph) and so 
  $f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid X = 0.6)$ is just a *scaled* version of the function $f_{X,Y}(0.6,y)$ with the scaling factor being $\displaystyle \frac 1{f_X(0.6)}$.  For *your* question, what does $f_{X,Y}(0.6,y)$ look like as a function of $y$? You *still* didn't do the previously-suggested thought problem? Do it now.

Finally, if you do things right, you will come up with the answer that the conditional pdf is a *uniform* density on an interval that will be immediately obvious without any need for computations of any kind.

Comment: I thought $f(x_0,y)=\frac{1}{\pi}\:\:\:\forall (x_0,y)\in B$. Should I get an uniform density function? How? I am getting $f_{Y|X}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-x^2}}$. Could please further explain so that I have an idea on how to solve this kinds of problems.

Comment: @PedroGomes Try _drawing_ the _graph_ of $f(0.3,y)$ **as a function of** $y$ _without_ spouting stuff like $(x_0,y) \in B$ which I don't understand too well, and I suspect you don't either.

Comment: The graph would be a parallel line from $(0,3;-\sqrt{0,91})$ to  $(0,3;\sqrt{0,91})$, where every element on the line takes the value, I think, $\frac{1}{\pi}$

Comment: @PedroGomes The value $\frac 1\pi$ is correct, but I am not sure what $(0,3; -\sqrt{0,91}$ means. I suspect that you are using the European style of notation where what in English is called the _decimal point_ $.$ is replaced by a _comma_ $,$, and if so, you are correct.  So, $f_{X.Y}(0.3,y)$ has constant value over an interval of the form $[-a,a]$ which tells us (or at least me) that $f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid X=0.3)$ also has constant value over the same interval (the conditional pdf is a _scaled_ version of $f_{X.Y}(0.3,y)$) and so the conditional pdf is a _uniform density_ over the interval.